# SQLite file containing garbage characters

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I'm currently using MonoTouch and SQLite in order to determine whether using a database with encryption is better than a standard .txt file with encryption.

I am attempting to use `RijndaelManaged` and other `System.Security.Cryptography` methods to encrypt my SQLite DB, but the DB becomes corrupt.

I have found the problem, but have no idea why it's happening or how to fix it. This is a basic SQLite file with a single table:

```
SQLite format 3@  -‚

øø?gtablenewnewCREATE TABLE new (id int(5), name vchar(255))
```

After using an [example online](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010), and encrypting this database, I get this:

```
SQLite format 3@  -�

��?gtablenewnewCREATE TABLE new (id int(5), name vchar(255))
```

This leaves the DB corrupt and unusable. Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Can anyone help me to encrypt this DB WITHOUT using SQLCipher?

**EDIT:** I have tried reading the raw DB in as bytes, and tried converting the bytes to a string, but no matter what encoding I use, I get \0 after the first line.

Comment: Try nvarchar.   The � is probably a unicode that could not be packed into char.   That is with SQL so not sure about sqlite and monotouch.

Comment: @Blam Thank you for trying, but I still get random characters. 


However, I think you have misunderstood what I'm trying to get at: the � has nothing to do with the SQL query, but the reminance of a character encrypted using RijndaelManaged

Comment: It look like an encoding issue. Can you show us the code you're using to encrypt/decrypt the file ?

Comment: @poupou I have linked the website example I am using: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010

Comment: Can you add the encryption and decryption routines?

Comment: @Ludo as I have explained previously, I have linked the website detailing the EXACT code that I have used. Once again: support.microsoft.com/kb/307010

Comment: Considering that you stated using `RijndaelManaged` while the linked sample code use `DESCryptoServiceProvider` and p/invoke into `kernel32.dll` to call `RtlZeroMemory` (which is unavailable in MonoTouch) it is not surprising that people ask you for the source code. Your edit about byte/string conversion is also strange since the linked sample code works on filenames.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your encrypt/decrypt routines I can only guess. Since you are using Rijndael, you need to ensure that you are setting the same [Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding.aspx) on the class for encrypt and decrypt. Also, make sure you call [FlushFinalBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock) when encrypting the data. That call is not listed in the sample (although they are calling `Close` which should call `FlushFinalBlock`, so if you are calling `Close` on the `CryptoStream` then you should be okay there).

**Edit**
I was thinking more about this. I think it may be related to the padding (again, without seeing your code its hard to say). Depending on the padding mode you choose, you will need to strip the padded bytes back off of the plain text after decrypting.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely places for your problem to live is when you're reading in the unencrypted database prior to encryption, or opening a new file to write out the freshly decrypted database.

As troubleshooting steps, you might consider reading in the raw database file as bytes and then writing it out, without any intervening encryption/decryption. If it still gets corrupted, the first thing I'd check is the encoding with which you're opening your output file.

Comment: I have tried pulling the data as byte[], and converting it to a string using Unicode, UTF-8 and ASCII encoding, but every single encoding returns the first line, then \0.

Comment: I'd try to avoid doing anything that involves converting it to or from a `string` altogether. The database file isn't a string--it's a sequence of bytes. The encryption/decryption also deal with byte sequences.

Comment: That's understandable. If that's the case, however, how am I meant to make the `byte[]` readable so that I can attempt to find the problem? I suppose I could explicitly cast each byte to `char`?

Comment: @nathanwhite, I guess what I'm saying is that if you never leave `byte[]`, you shouldn't have any encoding problems to deal with--those only creep up in `byte[]` to `string` and back.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The main problem with that is that when I encrypt and then decrypt, it is all in `byte[]` and never changes. I was trying to change it to a `string` in an attempt to debug.